# How to get Virtualdub to encode videos at the right speed?

Tags: conversion, speed, video-editing, virtualdub

I encoded my videos with Virtualdub. Since the video was 0.3 FPS and the output was wrong I decided to set the FPS to 15. Now my video is roughly 2-3 x faster. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following article describes how to ["Modify the Speed of an Avi Video File Using VirtualDub"](http://www.tutorialsroom.com/tutorials/av/modify_avi_speed.html).
Check this to find out how to undo the speed modification.